# A problem which reverses the definition of a bounded operator

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I've encontered a problem that appears simple, almost like it's a definition of a bounded operator, but with a reversed inequality sign... and I can't seem to find my way to a solution.

Any suggestions appreciated!

*Note:* $X$ and $Y$ are Banach (or even Hilbert) spaces.

**Problem:**

$ A:X \to Y $ is a bounded linear operator. Let $ A(X) = Y$, and $ y_n \to y_0 $ in $ Y $.

Prove that there exists $ c > 0 $, and a sequence $ x_n $ in $ X$, so that $ x_n \to x_0 $ , $ Ax=y $ , and $ \lVert x_n\rVert \le c\lVert y_n\rVert$

Comment: Do you have the open mapping theorem and its friends?

Comment: My biggest problem is that a lot of technical terms are different in my language, so I'm having trouble googling for directions. That theorem seems helpful, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to consider $\dot{A} : X/\mathcal{N}(A)\rightarrow Y$, which is continuous and a linear bijection between $X/\mathcal{N}(A)$ and $Y$. So the inverse of $\dot{A}$ is continuous, and the statement of that continuity gives you what you want.

Comment: I've found the following corrollaries of the open mapping theorem: Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces and let $T \in B(X,Y)$ be onto $Y$.

**(i)** If $T$ is one-to-one, then $T^{−1}$ is a bounded operator.

**(ii)** There is a constant $M > 0$ such that for every $y \in Y$ there is $x \in T^{−1}(y)$
satisfying $\lVert x\rVert_X \le M\lVert y\rVert_Y$.


**(iii)** Y is isomorphic to $X/Ker(T)$.